# Rotating my Earth in an animation

Tags: animation

I would like to animate my earth model by rotating it around an axis to be able to see all sides of it during the animation. I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any help, as this is a project for my 3D animation class. Thanks! You can get the file [here](https://drive.google.com/a/warriors.winnacunnet.org/file/d/0ByNdNuyKiJvbbUhzdl9PVmpHNWc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: What part of the animation process are you having trouble with?

Comment: I just finished modeling the Earth but I have never animated anything in blender so I don't really know where to go from here. I just want a simple rotation of the sphere to see all sides of it.

Comment: please post your .blend file [with this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). No google account needed, free, BSE friendly.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what keyframes are, this will be fairly simple. If you don't know what keyframes are... that's a bit beyond the scope of this site.

Basically, you'll make a keyframe at the beginning of you animation (usually frame 1). To do this, press <kbd>i</kbd> and select "Rot." This will record the rotation of your planet, and make sure that the rotation IS that value, until it gets changed by another keyframe.

Next, scrub a few frames later (30 frames is 1 second, so 30-40 frames will be fine). Then rotate your planet on whatever axis you are wanting, and then press <kbd>i</kbd> again, and select "Rot" again. This records the new rotation, and makes sure that the rotation IS that value ON that frame. In between this frame and your first keyframe, Blender will automatically "blend" between the two rotation values, and you'll get rotation.

If you search YouTube for "beginner Blender animation" you will find lots of good results.